# Unmet dependencies on apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, elementary-os

I got the following problems while trying to upgrade

```
*david@david-K42F:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for david:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libreoffice : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu1~precise1) but 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 is installed
libreoffice-base : Depends: libreoffice-base-core (= 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1) but 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 is installed
            Depends: libreoffice-base-drivers (= 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1) but 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 is installed
            Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1) but 
1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 is installed
libreoffice-base-drivers : Breaks: libreoffice-base (< 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~) but 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1 is installed
libreoffice-core : Breaks: libreoffice-base (< 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1) but 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.*
```

then I tried using the `apt-get -f install` and I get the following error

```
*david@david-K42F:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libnumber-compare-perl libnet-ip-perl libnet-dns-perl libdate-calc-xs-perl
libcdr-0.0-0 libfile-find-rule-perl libwps-0.2-2 liborcus-0.6-0 libwpd-0.9-9
libdate-calc-perl libcarp-clan-perl libtext-glob-perl libvisio-0.0-0 libwpg-0.2-2
libmspub-0.0-0 libdigest-hmac-perl libbit-vector-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
libreoffice libreoffice-base
Suggested packages:
libreoffice-grammarcheck openclipart-libreoffice pstoedit libreoffice-officebean
libreoffice-gcj libreoffice-report-builder
The following packages will be upgraded:
libreoffice libreoffice-base
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 76 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,738 kB of archives.
After this operation, 915 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
libreoffice-base libreoffice
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-base:
libreoffice-base depends on libreoffice-base-core (= 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1); however:
Version of libreoffice-base-core on system is 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1. libreoffice-base depends on libreoffice-base-drivers (= 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1);
however: Version of libreoffice-base-drivers on system is 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1. libreoffice-base depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1); however: Version of libreoffice-core on system is 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1. libreoffice-core (1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1) breaks libreoffice-base (<< 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1) and is installed.
Version of libreoffice-base to be configured is 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1. libreoffice-base-drivers (1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1) breaks libreoffice-base (<< 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~) and is installed.
Version of libreoffice-base to be configured is 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice-base (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-report-builder-bin: libreoffice-report-builder-bin depends on libreoffice-base; however: Package libreoffice-base is not configured yet. dpkg: error processing libreoffice-report-builder-bin (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
            No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice:
libreoffice depends on libreoffice-base; however: Package libreoffice-base is not configured yet.
libreoffice depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu1~precise1); however: Version of libreoffice-core on system is 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1.
libreoffice depends on libreoffice-report-builder-bin; however: Package libreoffice-report-builder-bin is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libreoffice (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
            Errors were encountered while processing:
libreoffice-base
libreoffice-report-builder-bin
libreoffice
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) david@david-K42F:~$*
```

and then I tried this

```
*david@david-K42F:~$ sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libreoffice : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu1~precise1) but 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 is installed
libreoffice-base : Depends: libreoffice-base-core (= 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1) but 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 is installed
            Depends: libreoffice-base-drivers (= 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1) but 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 is installed
            Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1) but 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 is installed
libreoffice-base-drivers : Breaks: libreoffice-base (< 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~) but 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1 is installed
libreoffice-core : Breaks: libreoffice-base (< 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1) but 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
david@david-K42F:~$*
```

I have no idea what to do.... also I'm not a linux user I moved from Windows to Elementary OS Luna, which is based strongly on Ubuntu 12.04

```
david@david-K42F:~$ sudo apt-get check
[sudo] password for david: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu1~precise1) but 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 is installed
 libreoffice-base : Depends: libreoffice-base-core (= 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1) but 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 is installed
                    Depends: libreoffice-base-drivers (= 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1) but 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 is installed
                    Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1) but 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 is installed
 libreoffice-base-drivers : Breaks: libreoffice-base (< 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~) but 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1 is installed
 libreoffice-core : Breaks: libreoffice-base (< 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1) but 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

---

```
david@david-K42F:~$ sudo dpkg -C
[sudo] password for david: 
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 libreoffice          office productivity suite (metapackage)
 libreoffice-report-builder-bin LibreOffice component for building database rep

The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 libreoffice-base     office productivity suite -- database




david@david-K42F:~$ apt-cache policy libreoffice libreoffice-core libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-base-drivers
libreoffice:
  Installed: 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu1~precise1
  Candidate: 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1
  Version table:
     1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 0
        500 ****://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu1~precise1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.5.7-0ubuntu6.1 0
        500 ****://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1 0
        500 ****://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 0
        500 ****://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
libreoffice-core:
  Installed: 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1
  Candidate: 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 0
        500 ****://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.5.7-0ubuntu6.1 0
        500 ****://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1 0
        500 ****://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 0
        500 ****://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
libreoffice-base:
  Installed: 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1
  Candidate: 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1
  Version table:
     1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 0
        500 ****://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:4.2.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~precise1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.5.7-0ubuntu6.1 0
        500 ****://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1 0
        500 ****://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 0
        500 ****://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
libreoffice-base-core:
  Installed: 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1
  Candidate: 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 0
        500 ****://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.5.7-0ubuntu6.1 0
        500 ****://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.5.4-0ubuntu1.1 0
        500 ****://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 0
        500 ****://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
libreoffice-base-drivers:
  Installed: 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1
  Candidate: 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.3.0-3ubuntu2~precise1 0
        500 ****://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
david@david-K42F:~$
```

It won't let me reinstall the eos repository

```
david@david-K42F:~$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:versable/elementary-update
Ignoring unknown parameter "update encrypted"
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 A supplementary PPA for elementaryOS Luna, providing elementaryOS based apps, third party icons for the elementary icon theme, additional plank themes and more.

For more elementaryOS visit http ://www.elementaryupdate.com/
For bug reports visit https ://bugs.launchpad.net/elementary-community
 More info: https ://launchpad.net/~versable/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-update
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 185, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 585, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 87, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException("Error: could not find a "
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template
```

============================
These are the contents of the source.list file

```
# deb cdrom:[elementary OS 0.2 _Luna_ - Stable amd64 (20130810)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[elementary OS 0.2 _Luna_ - Stable amd64 (20130810)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[elementary OS 0.2 _Luna_ - Stable amd64 (20130810)]/ precise main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ precise-getdeb games
deb-src http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ precise-getdeb games
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get check`, `sudo dpkg -C`, `apt-cache policy libreoffice libreoffice-core libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-base-drivers`, `cat /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}` and `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: It won't let me write the other outputs it says i need more reputation to post more than 2 links , so I changed all the "http" into "****" so it would let me post

Comment: If you use indentation, you could paste as code and the link restriction will be rendered mutt

Comment: I'll do that.. i'll take a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

You have a PPA that is causing problems, the best course of action is remove it and downgrade the packages:

```
sudo sed -i 's/deb\ http:\/\/ppa\.launchpad\.net/#deb\ http:\/\/ppa\.launchpad\.net/' /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install libreoffice-base-drivers_ libreoffice-base-core/precise-updates libreoffice-base/precise-updates libreoffice-core/precise-updates libreoffice/precise-updates
```

An explanation of what the above does:

1. Disable all PPA's on your system
2. Update the package list
3. With apt-get, purge the `libreoffice-base-drivers` and downgrade every other package to the ones in `precise-updates`.

The last line can also be used as:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends libreoffice-base-drivers
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-base-core/precise-updates libreoffice-base/precise-updates libreoffice-core/precise-updates libreoffice/precise-updates
```

Comment: Thank you very much Braiam that solved the dependencies problems, after executing the 3rd line i got the message that the libreoffice-base-drivers couldn't be found but I'm guessing that was causing problems right? anyway i will stop adding repositories that are not from elementary or ubuntu thank you very much

Comment: Hmm Braiam... something very weird just happened, now my OS thinks it's ubuntu and not elementary os (in the grub selection screen it sais ubuntu instead of elementary os),the update manager is offering me to upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 and also I'm no longer able to see the list of repositories in the update manager nor the synaptic package manager.... any idea of what happened??

Comment: @DavidjorgeNordmann elementary OS is just a bunch of PPA's over the base Ubuntu system. Just look for elementary entries in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` that are disabled and enable them removing the `#` character at the start.

Comment: All the elementary entries are gone, I tried reinstalling the elementary community software repository and it won't let me, edited the question so you can see the output.. also the software center isn't working anymore

Comment: @DavidjorgeNordmann they should be there, check the output of `grep -P 'elementary' /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*}`.

Comment: Just to let you know, you don't have to write out the string again, you can do something like this: `/ppa\.launchpad\.net/s/^/#/`

Comment: Something is weird when using the grep command I see them but when I open the source.list file they don't appear.. I have written in the question the contents of the source.list file...

Comment: hmm Chris Down I don't know where I have to write what you suggested...I'm just a windows user who switched to elementary os

Comment: @DavidjorgeNordmann you are complicating things more than what they should. `grep` checks the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file *and* the files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory. Is not just one file, but several.

Comment: Ok I have oppened all the files of elementary and removed all the #, still the problem persists... the software center opens and closes down automatically and the synaptic package manager won't let me see the repositories.. and the update manager still offers me to update to ubuntu 14.04.1